# One class classification with libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, supervised-learning

A quick recap for what I want to do, I want to determine if a text is written by the same author or not. Thus I use one-class classification. 

In my training set (18 samples), it looks like this (for simplifying, I used x as data value):

```
1 1:x 2:x "until" 200:x
1 1:x 2:x "until" 200:x
```

In my testing set (3 samples), it looks like this (for simplifying, I used y as data value):

```
1 1:y 2:y "until" 200:y
```

For data preparation (training and testing set), I set upper and lower scaling limit to +1/-1

```
-l -1 -u 1
```

For training, I use svm_type is one class svm, kernel type is Sigmoid. Yet the accuracy is 0%

```
optimization finished, #iter = 13
obj = 22.901769047004553, rho = 5.476401914859387
nSV = 11, nBSV = 6
Accuracy = 0.0% (0/21) (classification)
```

Can someone show me what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tune the parameters.

`nu` is an upper bound on the fraction of training errors and a lower bound of the fraction of support vectors. With such setting, basically the amount `nu`(0.01 means 1% for example) of the data can be rejected and flagged as an outlier.

Also try to tune `gamma` and `coef0` values in Sigmoid kernel.

Although it may not be the direct factor that causes your zero training accuracy, I suggest you scale the data by yourself instead of libsvm's maximum-minimum scaling, check [standard scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Standardization).

```
 x_mean = mean(x);
 x_std = std(x);
 x = (x - x_mean)./x_std;
```

Then use the same `x_mean` and `x_std` value to scale your test data.